# How to save modifications made to DOM elements?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

It is possible to save the modifications I made using jquery to the elements of the DOM?
What I want is: after you insert hex code intro the input text and "#div1" color was changed, when you reload the page the color you inserted to be saved.
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<div id="div1">


<input type="text" id="ui"/>
<input type="button" onclick="ct()" value="enter hex color"/>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function ct(){ 
$('#div1').css('background-color', "#" + $('#ui').val());
} 


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"It is possible to <insert goal here>"* is usually **Yes.**, assuming you aren't restricted to what technologies you can use, i'd suggest refraining from including that in your question and just getting to the question. In your case you can save it in a cookie, localstorage, on your server via ajax requests, etc.

Comment: Essentially you want the user to define a session specific style sheet.  This is not trivial.  You need at least local storage (cookies) or a sever side database that tracks the CSS changes on a session session basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Storage) - it [can be used](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) in all modern browsers (including IE8).

since you're already using jQuery, have a look at the following example:

```
$(function() {
  // grab your elements
  var $div = $('#div1');
  var $input = $('#ui');
  var $button = $('#ui-save'); // TODO: add this id to the button

  // fetch value from storage
  var initial = window.localStorage && localStorage.getItem('background');
  // set to whatever was in storage, if any
  if (initial) {
    $div.css('background', initial);
  }
  // bind to the input
  $button.on('click', function() {
    var color = $input.val();
    window.localStorage && localStorage.setItem('background', color);
    $div.css('background', color);
  })
});
```

Note that `window.localStorage &&` is there to make it work in browsers that do not know localStorage. In those browsers the color is still editable, but won't be saved across page reloads.

Answer (score 2):

Create a simple JQuery cookie to store the value. Then reference the cookie when the page loads!

I recommend using an 'id' for the button, but this code uses your HTML sample code with JQuery selector

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

     //store value 
     $('input[type=button]').click( function () {
          $.cookie("color", null);  //clear cookie in order to set the value
          $.cookie("color", $('#ui').val() ); //set cookie
          $('#div1').css('background-color', "#" + $.cookie("color") ); 
     });

     //reference cookie to set the color, happens on every HTML page load
     $('#div1').css('background-color', "#" + $.cookie("color"));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of a database or server-side scripting or cookie.

When you hit submit, you need to send that hex code to a database or other data storage service. And when you load the html page, it has to query that hex color from the database.

It will not work as is.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to actually change the output HTML source on the next page load using client-side javascript techniques alone.

You could however persist the color selection via cookie or HTML5 localStorage and apply it again using javascript on the next page load.

If you actually want to modify the output source code, you could either set a cookie that the server knows how to interpret to change the source that is output, or you could perhaps use an AJAX call to go to script that would either actually modify the static source code file or again, set some configuration that would change how the source is output.

Answer (score 0):

Use cookie is the best way to solve the issue.

```
function ct(){ 
    if($('#ui').val() == " " && document.cookie != ""){
        var color = document.cookie;
    }elseif($('#ui').val() != " "){
        color = $('#ui').val();
        document.cookie = color;
    }else{
        color = "defaultcolor";
    }
    $('#div1').css('background-color',color );
}
```